# Use LINQ to find nodes in xml document where nodes at different levels have same name

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

```
<category>
   <category>
       <category>
       </category>
   </category>
</category>
<category>
   <category>
       <category>
       </category>
   </category>
</category>
```

I have an xml segment as above where many of the child nodes have the same name as the parent nodes, repeating multiple levels deep. Using LINQ to XML I would  like to query 
1) just the top level nodes and 
2)  all the second level nodes and their descendants. 
Normally I could use .Descendents("category") or .Element() if  the node names were unique, but I cant find any way of specifying a level/depth in the XML hierarchy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1) just the top level nodes**

`Elements` method takes only element that are directly under current node, so use it to get the top level of `category` elements:

```
var topCategories = source.Elements("category");
```

**2) all the second level nodes and their descendants**

Combine `Elements` and `Descendants` to get that:

```
var topCategories = source.Elements("category").Descendants("category");
```

In both examples `source` is an `XElement` that is parent of the `category` section. E.g. `categories` in following document:

```
<root>
    <elements>
        <element />
        <element />
    </elements>
    <categories>
        <category>
            <category>
                <category>
                    <category />
                </category>
            </category>
        </category>
        <category>
            <category>
                <category />
            </category>
        </category>
    </categories>
</root>
```